# Can't access files of bind mounter volume during build process

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I attach myself to the container and check the files inside /app I can see my host content inside valve_controller, modify it, etc.

I can't see the files during the build process (RUN ls /app/ trows nothing). I need to verify the code and then compile it.

Are volumes mounted after the build generation?

Which option do I have that doesn't involve COPY?

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  valve_controller:
    container_name: "valve_controller"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./valve_controller/Dockerfile
    working_dir: /app
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - ./valve_controller:/app
```

Dockerfile

```
VOLUME /app
RUN ls /app/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Volumes are mounted only when the container is run, not during the build process. This is intentional, since the image generation should not depend on anything outside your build context (the directory where your Dockerfile is). If you need any files during image build, you should `COPY` them in.

Answer (score 0):

Volumes are mounted the moment you run the container. Therefore you can't refer to the files during the build process.

Adding a `command` tag in the docker-compose with a list of commands that need to run separated with && or ; would do the trick.

It's also possible to create and initial image with the volume and import that one.